# can't ping to a friend's computer

Tags: networking

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed and I recently installed the same version from the same CD on my friend's computer. When I try to ping him I don't get any response, when I press Ctrl C to terminate `ping` it says it sent some number of packets, but none of them were received, 100% packet loss. I thought he might have a firewall installed, but that's unlikely because I just installed his Ubuntu. I read `iptables` comes with Ubuntu, but if so, why can he ping me and I can't ping him?

The two computers are not connected to a shared network, I'd like to ping him just like I can `ping www.google.com`.

Comment: Whats his ip address and what is the ping command you are using?

Comment: We need more information. How are the two computers connected? Are they on the same network? Is it through via wired or wireless connections? What exactly do you type to ping in the two computers? Do you type their local IP addresses? Do you type their names? **Please edit your original question above with new information.**

Comment: @user68186 Edited.

Comment: You're probably pinging his router, and he is pinging yours. Not necessarily a Ubuntu problem.

Comment: @Jos Ubuntu is my (and his too) operating system, where else would this go? Is there a stackexchange for networking?

Comment: @shoham we still need more information. What is your IP address, and what is his? If you don't want to share the IP addresses, you need to tell us if you're pinging private or public IP addresses? Are you pinging public IPs across the internet? How did you find out the IP addresses? Are they directly assigned to the computer, or are you behind a router using a private IP, but you're pinging the routers? If you're pinging across the internet, your ISP might be blocking it. Try installing and running `traceroute -n <IPaddressHere>` to see where the pings stop.

Comment: Actually, probably less likely the ISP, but rather his router blocking it.

Comment: @AlaaAli I got the addresses from `whatismyip.com`. `traceroute -n` shows me 14 IP addresses and then just `* * *` - I don't know what that means. The 14th IP address is not the IP I tracerouted (his IP). And no I'm not pinging IP's like `192.168.1.1`, I'm not an idiot...

Comment: I am not calling you an idiot nor did I mean to offend you. You did not provide us enough information, so I do not know how much you know. I always assume the asker has the least probable knowledge if the question does not have enough information. Also, answers/comments here help others, so being as detailed as possible (from our end and yours) helps them too. Anyways, I've posted an answer.

Comment: The IP you'd get from `whatismyip.com` would be the IP of your router/modem as seen from the internet. So, if you're pinging that IP, you're not pinging his PC directly but rather the modem/router his PC is connecting to. I don't know if this is real code, but basically what you want is something to the nature of ping INTRANET_IP@INTERNET_IP. EX: `ping 192.168.0.1@152.235.100.34`

Comment: Further googling says this is technically possible but could create security nightmares. http://www.speedguide.net/faq_in_q.php?qid=376

Comment: That `ping 192.168.0.1@152.235.100.34` code you suggested is not possible. Also, adding the machine to the router's DMZ list means that you need to assign a public static IP to the machine, or configure NATing on the router. Even so, all of this won't do any good if something along the way is blocking the pings, not his router =).

Comment: Yeah, that PING was a longshot. I'm pretty sure this is just ICMP stuff and not something along the way: "Most computers will, by default, automatically respond to ICMP echo request (pings). If you can't ping a machine, it is likely that it is behind a NAT router or some sort of firewall. Many routers/gateways block ICMP echo requests (or simply drop ICMP when under high load).  Under Unix-like OSes, the traceroute utility uses UDP by default, while under Windows tracert uses ICMP."

Answer (score 2):

A very good way of troubleshooting why pings don't work can be done using `traceroute`:

```
traceroute -n <IPaddress>
```

If it is not installed, you can install it using `sudo apt-get install traceroute`.

From your comments on the question, you ran traceroute and it stopped at a certain IP address and displayed `* * *` asterisks afterwards, something like this:

```
traceroute to <IPaddress>, 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  1.1.1.1  75.415 ms  75.348 ms  75.298 ms
 2  2.2.2.2  28.026 ms  28.025 ms  30.207 ms
 3  3.3.3.3  40.006 ms  39.999 ms  45.287 ms
 4  4.4.4.4  118.244 ms  90.393 ms  90.350 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
```

This means that the traceroute got blocked and did not reach the destination. The network device `4.4.4.4` (or the device after it) is the device that is blocking the connection. Since you're going over the internet, I assume that these devices are not controlled by you. This means that you will not be able to ping your friend's IP because something on the internet is blocking it. ***He*** can ping you because there's nothing blocking pings originating from his network (that can also include the `4.4.4.4` device that is blocking your pings).

You can double check this by trying to ping his IP address from a different device, a device that is in a different LAN network than you, to verify that probably no one can ping his IP address (and that his ISP is probably blocking it).

Comment: So I can't ping him because some router along the way has a decent firewall? That's weird... Can I make a detour around that router or something like that? Also, I asked another friend of mine to try to ping him, he couldn't either, him and me are on the same ISP while the friend we are trying to ping is on another ISP.

Comment: Yes, a router along the way has a firewall that's blocking it. It's not weird at all man =), ISPs (or networks along the way) can block it. You can't make a detour around that router because you'll need access to the routing table of one of the routers along the way before you hit the firewall and edit them to go somewhere else. Since you and your third friend are on the same ISP, we still can't say for sure which "side" of the network is blocking it (your or the destination's ISP).

Comment: Scratch that. Since you saw 14 IP addresses in your traceroute, it's probably not your ISP that's blocking it, but the destination's, or something along the way. To have some fun, ask your third friend to run a `traceroute` too (it can be run on Windows using `tracert -d <IP>`. Windows will probably give you different results; it can go further or even get blocked earlier because Windows uses a different traceroute way). Check if both your traceroutes stop at the same device. Remove the `-n` option (or `-d` in Windows) in the traceroute command to actually see what the IP addresses resolve to.

Comment: I asked him. In the meanwhile, I'm curious, are those routers I'm routing through my ISP's and his ISP's only? Or are they also routers of other customers of the ISP? I mean, could it be that if I block port 80 on my firewall and someone in my ISP tries to log in to `www.google.com`, and I happen to be the shortest route to Google servers, could I deny him the connection? If so... that's just really dumb.

Comment: No. The routers along the way are not just your ISP's and his, but probably other ISPs, depending on where you and him are located. Those are called the internet backbone routers. Read more about the internet backbone [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_backbone) and [here](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/internet/basics/internet-infrastructure4.htm). The ISP will never use customers as "hops" because 1) we probably only have 1 connection to the ISP, so how would the traffic go through us; it'll end up going back the same way it came in, 2) our links are very slow, in comparison.

Comment: Just to point out, the comments section are not really for discussions. You can jump into [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead.